# what is the meaning of "Smiling upon"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

what is the meaning of "Smiling upon"?

Mr. Somes said: "Mr. President, would it be improper for me to inquire
whether there has been any pressure brought to bear upon you to defer
the enforcement of the Proclamation?" To which the President replied
"Under these circumstances that question is perfectly proper, as we are
all friends." (**Smiling upon the company**). "It is taking all my nerve and
strength to withstand such a pressure." At this point the gentlemen drew
around him and spoke together in low tones, Mr. Lincoln saying least of
all. At last he turned to me, and laying his hand upon my head, uttered
these words in a manner I shall never forget. "My child, you possess a
very singular gift, but that it is of God I have no doubt. I thank you for
coming here to-night. It is more important than perhaps anyone present
can understand. I must leave you all now, but I hope I shall see you
again." He shook me kindly by the hand, bowed to the rest of the
company, and was gone. We remained an hour longer, talking with Mrs.
Lincoln and her friends, and then returned to Georgetown. Such was my
first interview with Abraham Lincoln, and the memory of it is as clear
and vivid as the evening on which it occurred.

source:http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html _ hos by acd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lincoln is surrounded by people, and is speaking publicly. After he made the first answer, he smiled at those around him before he gave his second answer. You can perhaps imagine that this is more than a person-to-person smile - it is bestowed upon all around him, maybe by looking at them in turn.

Answer (score 0):

"Smiled upon" sounds a bit old-fashioned to me. It suggests that Lincoln was bestowing his smile upon the people around in him, in the same way that we would say that the sun shone "upon" the people or the rain fell "upon" the people. The author may also mean that because Lincoln was very tall for his time, he had to smile down at others. It also brings to mind the expression, "Fortune smiled upon me" which means to have good luck or success. This may reflect the author's feeling that Lincoln was a great man who had a spiritual power to bless others, which is also suggested by the description of Lincoln placing his hand on the author's head.